# php - Yii2 ActiveQuery select joinWith for API

Tags: php, api, yii2-advanced-app

my Customer model

```
public function getAddress() {
   return $this->hasMany(Address::className(), ['address_id' => 'address_id']);
}
```

my Customer controller

```
$query = Customer::find()
          ->alias(['a'])
          ->select(['a.*', 'b.address_name', 'b.address_longitude', 'b.address_latitude'])
          ->joinWith([address b])
          ->asArray()
          ->all()
return ["data" => $query];
```

results :

```
{
  "data": [
     {
       "id": "123",
       "name": "abc",
       "address_name": "bcd",
       "address_logitude": "12312.1231",
       "address_latitude": "11232.11213",
       "address": []
     }
  ]
}
```

expected

```
{
  "data": [
     {
       "id": "123",
       "name": "abc",
       "address": [
         "address_name": "bcd",
         "address_logitude": "12312.1231",
         "address_latitude": "11232.11213",
       ]
     }
  ]
}
```

help me please.. i've tried to find the solution for a few days, but still nothing. 
hope to find the solution soon. :D

Comment: Could you show the model attributes? Currently not able to figure out why there is a {"address": []}

Comment: @Chun model attributes of Customer?

Comment: yes. Actually, I suggest you process the return array right after the db select call

Answer (score -1, accepted):

what you expect is [eager loading](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#data-in-batches).

You can use `with()` instead of joinWith():

```
$customers = Customer::find()
      ->alias(['a'])
      ->select(['a.*', 'b.address_name', 'b.address_longitude', 'b.address_latitude'])
      ->with([address b])
      ->all()
```

you have to change `getAddress()` as follows:

```
public function getAddress() {
 return $this->hasMany(Address::className(), ['address_id' => 'id']);
}
```

for generating this array you can do like follows:

```
$result = [];
foreach($customers as $customer) {
   $result['data'][] = [
      "id" => $customer->id,
      "name" => $customer->name,
      "address"=> [
         "address_name" => $customer->address->name,
          ...
      ]
   ]
}
```

Comment: i alr tried using with() instead of joinWith(), but in the end the result : the address didn't join into the query.

Comment: sorry, i miss something from ur answer, it work but not as i expected. i want the value of the address inside of an array.

Comment: you can make your required array with php array. it can't handle by activerecord.

Comment: if im using joinWith() without select particular column, it can return in array. but after im using select, it can't..
and do u have an example on how make it as an array for address?